# DB Error: unknown error - [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_contact

Tags: joomla, error, database, mysql, civicrm-contact

it's fresh install of CiviCrm into my Joomla, run with UniserverZ
(assume all Apps are in latest version)

[image: Joomla Admin Panel]

When I clicked CiviCRM, in Components, there was a DB Error: unknown error
In the joomla/media/civicrm/ConfigAndLog displays

```
Mar 28 07:58:42  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , display_name , preferred_language , hash , first_name , last_name , communication_style_id , email_greeting_id , postal_greeting_id , addressee_id ) VALUES ('Individual' ,  NULL , 'User, Super' , 'Super User' , 'en_US' , '4657797a1e8c1944237e5e83dc3f8b38' , 'Super' , 'User' ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1436 ** Thread stack overrun:  8640 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , display_name , preferred_language , hash , first_name , last_name , communication_style_id , email_greeting_id , postal_greeting_id , addressee_id ) VALUES ('Individual' ,  NULL , 'User, Super' , 'Super User' , 'en_US' , '4657797a1e8c1944237e5e83dc3f8b38' , 'Super' , 'User' ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1436 ** Thread stack overrun:  8640 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , display_name , preferred_language , hash , first_name , last_name , communication_style_id , email_greeting_id , postal_greeting_id , addressee_id ) VALUES ('Individual' ,  NULL , 'User, Super' , 'Super User' , 'en_US' , '4657797a1e8c1944237e5e83dc3f8b38' , 'Super' , 'User' ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 ,  1 )  [nativecode=1436 ** Thread stack overrun:  8640 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.]"]
)


Mar 28 07:58:42  [info] $backTrace = #0 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\Error.php(232): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB.php(984): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: unknown error", -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...")
#3 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...")
#4 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -1, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-1, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...", "1436 ** Thread stack overrun:  8640 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 12...")
#7 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...")
#9 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(2446): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...")
#10 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\packages\DB\DataObject.php(1068): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO civicrm_contact (contact_type , contact_sub_type , sort_name , di...")
#11 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php(525): DB_DataObject->insert()
#12 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Contact.php(214): CRM_Core_DAO->save()
#13 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Contact.php(308): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::add((Array:12))
#14 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Contact\BAO\Contact.php(1992): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::create((Array:12))
#15 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\UFMatch.php(298): CRM_Contact_BAO_Contact::createProfileContact((Array:5), (Array:0))
#16 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\BAO\UFMatch.php(118): CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronizeUFMatch(Object(Joomla\CMS\User\User), "121", "temp@temp.com", "Joomla", NULL, "Individual", TRUE)
#17 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm.php(97): CRM_Core_BAO_UFMatch::synchronize(Object(Joomla\CMS\User\User), FALSE, "Joomla", "Individual", TRUE)
#18 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civicrm\civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#19 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php(382): require_once("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\components\com_civi...")
#20 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\libraries\src\Component\ComponentHelper.php(357): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator/components/com_civi...")
#21 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#22 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\libraries\src\Application\AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#23 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\libraries\src\Application\CMSApplication.php(303): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#24 C:\Users\USER\Desktop\UniServerZ\www\joomla\administrator\index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#25 {main}
```

I'm a newbie, don't know what went wrong? Please help

Comment: This sounds like something is wrong at the server level with the database configuration. You could probably ask your hosting provider.

Comment: it was run in UniserverZ, a localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part of the error that matters is this part:

```
Thread stack overrun:  8640 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.
```

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/ under MySQL configuration - it needs to be 192k or higher. FYI the thread_stack variable needs to be set in the mysql configuration file and mysql needs to be restarted - you can't change it on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your help Demerit
I found the my.ini file in UniserverZ
I searched google to look for the same problem but it told me to find my.cnf file to edit the thread_stack, I was in frustration last night for unable to find one.


[image]

Comment: Great! Good googling.